# How can I build without webpack error in solana project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, vercel, solana

Can anyone solve this please... I am getting it in the browser console.

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , codecs_data_structures_1.getBytesCodec) is
> not a function at
> ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/state.js
> (state.ts:7:1) at options.factory (react refresh:6:1) at
> **webpack_require** (bootstrap:22:1) at fn (hot module replacement:61:1) at
> ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/index.js
> (index.ts:4:1) at options.factory (react refresh:6:1) at
> **webpack_require** (bootstrap:22:1) at fn (hot module replacement:61:1) at
> ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/cjs/extensions/tokenMetadata/actions.js (actions.ts:4:1) at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

I want to run this project on localhost and deploy to the vercel.

Comment: you should be posting related code as well.